# Spring Bean autowiring

Tags: spring, autowired

In Spring, can a bean created in the application context be autowired to a bean created in the root context. For the past few hours, I have been trying to do so, but it does not seem to work. Is there a way?

Comment: The root context (the parent) cannot "see" the beans from the children. The children CAN "see" the beans from the parent.

Comment: great! that solves it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root context (the parent) cannot "see" the beans from the children. The children CAN "see" the beans from the parent.
In support of this statement, one can set as "parent" an `ApplicationContext` when creating another `ApplicationContext`: multiple types of contexts have constructors where one of the parameters is another context. What this means is that the newly created context know who is its parent but the parent has no idea who are its children. It's a design decision for an `ApplicationContext`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class like this below:

```
package your.package;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;


public class YourApplicationContext {
    private static ApplicationContext instance;

    public static ApplicationContext getInstance() {
        try {
        if(instance == null){
            synchronized ( YourApplicationContext.class ){
                if(instance == null){
                    instance = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
                }
            }
        }

        return instance;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Also add an applicationContext.xml into your resources folder in below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="your.package" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" />

</beans>
```

I added xml file as if you are using Spring 3.0 version.